# I had a problem with javascript alert fuunction

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, alert

I am having 3 kind of swf players and if any one of player is playing all others should pause.

1 st one - audioPlayer - `autoplay = true;`
2 nd one - audioPlayer - `autoplay = false;`
3 rd one - audioPlayer - `autoplay = false;`

If 2nd and 3rd paused or ended then 1st one should continue if it was not paused.

This is my **java script** code.

```
function videoPlaying(val){
    tmp = val;
}    
function sendTojs(value){
        if(value == "end" || value == "pause"){
         thisMovie("movie0").sndToAS("pause");
         alert("done");
    }
    for(i=0; i<=7; i++){
         var mov="movie"+i;
        if(tmp!=mov){
                thisMovie(mov).sndToAS("resume");
            }
         }
        }
```

here `sndToAS` is my **actionscript** function and **tmp** will have the strings "resume", "pause" and "end". I have used `externalInterface.callBack` in AS3.

**actionscript3.0**

within `callback` function

```
if(val == "pause")
{
    videoPlay();
}
```

**My problem:**
   if I use the `alert` function within `sendTojs` then the condition is working else not. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If adding an alert fixes the problem, then it's a timing problem.  The alert stops execution until you dismiss it, radically changing the timing of the code.  Perhaps there's an asynchronous operation that needs to complete?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a situation where the display is not being updated until the script pauses (in this case for an alert). Try using `setTimeout()`.

```
if(tmp2=="end")
 {
    thisMovie("movie0").sndToAS("pause"),
    setTimeout(function() {},1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you said

> I have used externalInterface.call in AS3

its not **externalInterface.call** its **ExternalInterface.addCallback**

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "sndToAS", myJsCallBack );
function myJsCallBack ( val:String ):void{
  switch( val ){ // do your validation in ActionScript
    case "pause":
      // do pause toggle here
      break;
    case "end":
      // do stop here
      break;
    case "start":
      // do start here
      break;
  }
}
```

In javaScript you need this

```
thisMovie("movie0").sndToAS(tmp);
```

Comment: I had no problem with `call` and `callBack` functions.

Comment: Then post all of your code seriously how do you expect anyone to help you when you only post a sliver of the offending code?????????